# how to change font family when change locale (language in i18n) in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a multi-language application and it will switch language via select input that toggle locale between 2 languages, on the other hand, I have 2 font-family that I want to toggle when the locale changed.

in _app.js

```
const {locale} = useRouter();
useEffect(() => {
  if(locale === "ur"){
    import("../styles/urdoFont.css");
  }else{
    import("../styles/persianFont.css");
  }
}, [locale]);
```

and in header component

```
<Link 
   href={{
      pathname: '/',
                    }}
      as={`/`}
      locale="fa"
 >
   <a>
     <Image
        src="/image/iran.svg"
        alt=""
        width="40"
        height="40"
     />
   </a>
 </Link>
 <Link 
      href={{
         pathname: '/ur',
      }}
      as={`/ur`}
      locale="ur"
    >
      <a>
        <Image
          src="/image/pakistan.svg"
          alt=""
          width="40"
          height="40"
        />
      </a>
 </Link>
```

Comment: Do you want to change font-family of what? In single component or global?

Comment: for example when click "fr" change url to `example.com/fr` and change font in all website to `frfont.wpff`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works for me. I'm using Next 13 and @next/font. I believe this should work with any version that supports @next/font

Here's what you do:

```
    import { googleFont1, googleFont2 } from "@next/font/google"
    import { useRouter } from "next/router.js"
    
    const font1 = googleFont1({
    ...options
    })
    
    const font2 = googleFont2({
    ...options
    })
    
    function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
      //check current local using the built-in router
      const { locale } = useRouter()
    
      return (
        <main
          //create a conditional statement based on the current locale
          className={`${
            locale === "en" ? 
            font1.className : 
            font2.className
          }`}
        >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </main>
      )
    }
    
    export default App
```

With this solution, both fonts are loaded in right on page load, but only one of them will be applied to the  tag at a given time.

Once the user changes languages, the font applied will change automatically.

Here's documentation on [@next/font](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/font). It's a great tool and have saved so much of development time as well as page load times!

Hope this helps!