# How to Implement Language-Specific Font Switching in Nextjs 13 for Arabic and English Text?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js 13 application where I need to implement language-specific font switching. Specifically, I want to use the "Raleway" font for English text and the "Rabar" font for Arabic text. How can I achieve this font switching behavior based on the language of the content? Any guidance on setting up the fonts, applying them to specific text elements,

```
import './assets/css/globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import localFont from '@next/font/local'
import { Raleway } from 'next/font/google'


//English Font
const raleway = Raleway({subsets: ['latin'], variable: '--font-raleway'})

//Arabic Font
const rabar = localFont({
  src: '/assets/fonts/Rabar.ttf',
  variable: '--font-rabar',
})


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${raleway.className} ${rabar.className}`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check over the locale being used. According to the given code, do as follows:

```js
import './assets/css/globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import localFont from '@next/font/local'
import { Raleway } from 'next/font/google'
import { useRouter } from "next/router"


//English Font
const raleway = Raleway({subsets: ['latin'], variable: '--font-raleway'})

//Arabic Font
const rabar = localFont({
  src: '/assets/fonts/Rabar.ttf',
  variable: '--font-rabar',
})


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const { locale } = useRouter()
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${locale === "en" ? raleway.classname : radar.classname}`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

reference taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75182930/13770585)

Comment: the solution you've provided switches fonts based on the user's language locale, which is not exactly what I'm aiming for. My website is primarily in English, but I want to apply the "Rabar" font only to user-generated Arabic content, while keeping the default "Raleway" font for the rest of the website's English content.